# How do you efficiently check for datas loaded in Angular 2+ components?

Tags: angular, api, asynchronous, loading

In angular i do the following in each of my component which communicate with an API :

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

    public datasLoaded: boolean = false;

    private datasALoaded: boolean = false;
    private datasBLoaded: boolean = false;
    private datasCLoaded: boolean = false;

    constructor(private api: MyAPIService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        fetchDatas();
    }

    fetchDatas() {
        this.api.getDatasA().subscribe({
            next: datas => {
                this.datasALoaded = true;
                this.checkDatasLoaded();
            }
        });

        this.api.getDatasB().subscribe({
            next: datas => {
                this.datasBLoaded = true;
                this.checkDatasLoaded();
            }
        });

        this.api.getDatasC().subscribe({
            next: datas => {
                this.datasCLoaded = true;
                this.checkDatasLoaded();
            }
        });
    }

    private checkDatasLoaded() {
        this.datasLoaded = this.datasALoaded && this.datasBLoaded && this.datasCLoaded;
    }
}
```

I have a variable for each request representing its status (loaded or not). And a public variable `datasLoaded` used in the template to aggregate the status of all requests and display content only if everything is loaded :

```
<div *ngIf="datasLoaded"></div>
```

That's working perfectly fine , but it's a pain to write for each component. Obviously every components are different , not the same requests , not the same number of requests , not the same behaviour when datas are loaded or not but i'm looking for a solution a bit more easy to write.

How do you handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You will not overcome 'datasLoaded' flag, but you could try to shorten the code or even do it as an utility with `forkJoin`

```
forkJoin({
  a:  this.api.getDatasA(),
  b:  this.api.getDatasA(),
  c:  this.api.getDatasA()
}).pipe(finalize(()=>this.datasLoaded=false)).subscribe(abc=>{
   abc.a  //a data here
   abc.b  //b data here
   abc.c  //c data here
});
```